# Slice in helm no matches found

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have the following `define` definition in helm:

```
{{- define "svc.envVars" -}}
{{- range .Values.envVars.withSecret }}
- name: {{ .key }}
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: {{ .secretName }}
      key: {{ .secretKey | quote }}
{{- end }}
{{- range .Values.envVars.withoutSecret }}
- name: {{ .name }}
  value: {{ .value | quote }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

and I am going to use it in `deployment.yaml`

```
  containers:
    - name: {{ .Release.Name }}
      image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
      imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
      {{- if .Values.envVars.enabled }}
      env:
      {{- include "svc.envVars" . | indent 10 }} 
      {{- end }}
      ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
      livenessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /
          port: http
      readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /
          port: http
      resources:
        {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
```

in `values.yaml` it is defined as follows:

```
envVars:
  enabled: false
  withSecret: []
  withoutSecret: []
```

then I tried to render:

```
helm template --debug user-svc \
  --set image.tag=0.1.0 \
  --set image.repository=user-svc \
  --set envVars.enabled=true \
  --set envVars.withSecret[0].key=POSTGRES_URL,envVars.withSecret[0].secretName=postgres_name,envVars.withSecret[0].secretKey=postgres_pw \
  --set envVars.withSecret[1].key=MYSQL_URL,envVars.withSecret[1].secretName=mysql_name,envVars.withSecret[1].secretKey=mysql_pw \
  ./svc
```

it shows me:

```
zsh: no matches found: envVars.withSecret[0].key=POSTGRES_URL,envVars.withSecret[0].secretName=postgres_name,envVars.withSecret[0].secretKey=postgres_pw
```

When I set the variables manually in `values.yaml`:

```
envVars:
  enabled: false
  withSecret:
    - key: POSTGRES_URL
      secretName: postgres_name
      secretKey: postgres_pw
    - key: MYSQL_URL
      secretName: mysql_name
      secretKey: mysql_pw  
  withoutSecret:
    - name: NOT_SECRET
      value: "Value of not serect"
```

then render it with:

```
helm template --debug user-svc \
  --set image.tag=0.1.0 \
  --set image.repository=user-svc \
  --set envVars.enabled=true \
  ./svc
```

then it works as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As is clearly indicated by the `zsh:` prefix, you're seeing the output from your shell, not helm; you need to quote those expressions because `[` and `]` are shell metacharacters

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue. Due to the fact, that ´[´ and ´]´ are interpreted by zsh.
You can use `noglob` to disable the globals. So, ´[´ and ´]´ are not interpreted.

```sh
noglob helm template --set lorem[0].ipsum=1337
```

In your example:

```sh
noglob helm template --debug user-svc \
  --set image.tag=0.1.0 \
  --set image.repository=user-svc \
  --set envVars.enabled=true \
  --set envVars.withSecret[0].key=POSTGRES_URL,envVars.withSecret[0].secretName=postgres_name,envVars.withSecret[0].secretKey=postgres_pw \
  --set envVars.withSecret[1].key=MYSQL_URL,envVars.withSecret[1].secretName=mysql_name,envVars.withSecret[1].secretKey=mysql_pw \
  ./svc
```

Sources:

- [Helm - zsh: no matches found: imagePullSecrets[0].name=regcred](https://imlc.me/helm-zsh-no-matches-found-imagepullsecrets-0-.name-regcred)¨